# Random value is chosen 2-3 times, then after that it's always 1

Tags: unity, c#, random

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class GenerateObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectPrefab;

    [Range(1, 100)]
    public int numberOfObjects = 1;
    public int maxDepth;
    [Range(1, 100)]
    public int posX = 1, posY = 1, posZ = 1;
    [Range(1, 100)]
    public int numberOfChildrenInLevel = 1;
    public bool randomNumberOfChildren = false;

    private GameObject parent;
    private int count = 0;
    private int oldNumberOfObjects;
    private int currentDepth;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        oldNumberOfObjects = numberOfObjects;

        parent = GameObject.Find("Generate Objects");

        StartCoroutine(SpawnObjects());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (oldNumberOfObjects != numberOfObjects)
        {
            StartCoroutine(SpawnObjects());
            oldNumberOfObjects = numberOfObjects;
        }
        else
        {
            StopAllCoroutines();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnObjects()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);

            if (objectPrefab != null)
            {
                GameObject go = InstantiateObjects(parent.transform);
                go.tag = "Instantiated Object";
                GenerateChildren(go);
            }

            count++;

            if (count == numberOfObjects)
            {
                StopAllCoroutines();
                break;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    GameObject child;
    private void GenerateChildren(GameObject go)
    {
        if (currentDepth < maxDepth)
        {
            if (randomNumberOfChildren)
            {
                int ggg = Random.Range(1, numberOfChildrenInLevel);
                numberOfChildrenInLevel = ggg;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChildrenInLevel; i++)
            {
                child = InstantiateObjects(null);
                child.transform.parent = go.transform;
            }

            currentDepth++;
            GenerateChildren(child);
        }
        else
        {
            currentDepth = 0;
        }
    }

    private GameObject InstantiateObjects(Transform parent)
    {
        return Instantiate(objectPrefab,
            new Vector3(Random.Range(0, posX), Random.Range(0, posY), Random.Range(0, posZ)),
            Quaternion.identity, parent);
    }

    public void ClearObjects()
    {
        GameObject[] instantiatedObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Instantiated Object");
        foreach (GameObject go in instantiatedObjects)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(go);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is with the `numberOfChildrenInLevel` variable.

When the flag `randomNumberOfChildren` is true, I want to generate random numbers:

```
if (randomNumberOfChildren)
{
    int ggg = Random.Range(1, numberOfChildrenInLevel);
    numberOfChildrenInLevel = ggg;
}
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChildrenInLevel; i++)
```

For example, I set the `numberOfChildrenInLevel` value to 41 in the inspector. It's picking a random number 2-3 times, then each time after that the picked number is 1, not random anymore. I see that the Range slider of the `numberOfChildrenInLevel` is moving in the inspector back to 1. I can't figure out why it's not generating more random numbers and why it's always generating the same value of 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is these two lines:

```
int ggg = Random.Range(1, numberOfChildrenInLevel);
numberOfChildrenInLevel = ggg;
```

Each time you run your function, the range that your random amount should roll gets smaller and smaller. And at one point it is just 1. If you want to keep it between 1 and 99, you should not save the result in the same variable that is responsible for the maximum amount